# How much should this homebrew ioun stone cost?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, homebrew-review, pricing

I want one of my NPCs to have a custom Ioun stone:

> #### Ioun stone, dark galena
>
> Aura moderate evocation; CL 12th
> Slot none; Weight —.
>
> With a command word, the user may activate or de-activate the fast-spinning mode of this stone. When in its fast-spinning mode it tries to hurt people who stands close to the owner: Each turn, the stone attacks one adjacent creature, chosen at random, using the BAB + mental ability modifier of the owner (the mental ability used is chosen when each Ioun stone is created). If it hits, the stone deals 1d4 bludgeoning damages.
>
> The owner's mount and any creatures carried by the user are excluded from potential targets.
>
> The stone stays in its fast-spinning mode until it is de-activated or separated from its owner.
>
> The stone can be targeted as a normal piece of equipment by maneuvers. A creature attacked by the stone gets a +2 circumstance bonus to its CMB during the next turn for steal or sunder maneuvers that target the stone.

There's capacity for these specific Ioun stones to stack if you have several, and that's intentional.

I am looking for a price that would be fair for such an item. I am thinking about 5,000 gp.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Although I think it obvious from omission, but does such an ioun stone have any benefit to the owner when not fast-spinning?

Comment: @royalmurder: not by itself. Like for the other ioun stones it is still an item you can cast silence or light on, so you may have a use for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

5,000 gp is approximately correct for an item that deals 1d4 damage each round.

The closest benchmark I can find is the Horned Helm (Magic Item Compendium, 8000 gp) which grants a secondary gore attack (-5 attack) dealing 1d8 plus half Strength modifier damage.

This ioun stone is essentially a weaker version of that item. It deals around half as much damage, doesn't let you pick between multiple targets, and hits adjacent allies (although allies will rarely be adjacent to this unless healing you, so it's not as strong a drawback as it may seem). On the upside, it's slotless. It uses the full base attack rather than -5, but since it uses mental ability scores it's weaker on a melee character, and a spellcaster is rarely in melee, so that aspect balances out.

So 5,000 gp is around the right price for this item. To prevent someone wearing multiple of these to become a human chainsaw, I suggest that such stones attempt to attack each other when many are worn at once.

Comment: Good call on benchmarking it.  I wouldn't have thought of comparing it to a bonus natural attack.

Comment: The differences between the *horned helm* and this are much more extreme than you let on. You can have multiple of these and they stack, but only one *horned helm*, so the slotless matters more than it otherwise might (most ioun stones don’t self-stack). You only get the “free” attack with a *horned helm* if you were full-attacking anyway, while this gets in a freebie every round no matter what. But on the other hand, the *horned helm* is a proper attack—it scales in all kinds of ways and can get all kinds of bonuses. This cannot get any bonuses at all, and the base damage is pitiful.

Comment: (Not saying that *horned helm* was a bad point of comparison—as @Ifusaso says, that’s quite clever and I wouldn’t have thought of it—but you should address the differences more.)

Comment: Nice analysis, especially with @KRyan's comment.

Comment: @KRyan Taking your further analysis into account, would you recommend the pricing of ~5,000 gp be different? You make further points for why it's both better and worse than the *Horned Helm*, but don't touch on how the additional points would affect the price.

Comment: @royalmurder If I had a suggestion for *that*, it would be in my own answer. In reality, I think the entire concept is incredibly toxic and bad for the game, and so would simply recommend *not having any such ioun stone  at all.* I may write such a suggestion up as an answer, perhaps, but I also may not. But ultimately, 5,000 gp is not enough to prevent game-breaking abuse of this ioun stone—and I do not mean game-breaking in the “overpowered” sense, but literally in the sense of breaking the assumptions of the game’s narrative. But at the same time, 5,000 gp for just one is a waste.

Comment: I think full BAB is a bit much. Also its just constantly making freebie attacks (and at what range?). This could also compound and disrupt concentration of enemies. Honestly the damage is pittance but this items seems kind of overpowered because it will always have a relevant chance to hit, and will always have the benefits that come with that (something that is always hitting, regardless of damage). With all these things in mind the price should go up. I vote 8000 gp.

Comment: I also think this item should break after X number of attacks.

Comment: The range is "one adjacent creature". It seems clear to me, how would you formulate it? Also it is far from "always hitting": I looked at different characters at different levels compared to monsters you could encounter at this level, and the chance to hit is less than an average blow from a martial character. If you want something that it always hitting you can get a wand of *magic missile*: it is cheap, at range, overcome DR, does full damage on incorporeal... while the stone just tries to hit a random adjacent creature (probably a foe but only if you were clever with your placement).

Answer (score 2):

Magic item crafting is (loosely) based off of a [table available here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic-items/#TOC-Magic-Item-Gold-Piece-Values).

Pertinent lines are:

> **Use-activated or continuous**  Spell level x caster level x 2,000 gp
>
> Note: If a continuous item has an effect based on a spell with a **duration measured in rounds, multiply the cost by 4**. If the duration of the spell is 1 minute/level, multiply the cost by 2, and if the duration is 10 minutes/level, multiply the cost by 1.5. If the spell has a 24-hour duration or greater, divide the cost in half.
>
> **No space limitation**: Multiply entire cost by 2

So we get (spell level times minimum caster level) x 2000 x duration modified x 2

Since no spell does 1d4 damage per round, we have to compare it to similar spells. Cantrips can deal 1d4 damage per round, but *take up your Standard action* so they are siginificantly weaker than one which is 'set and forget'. The spells *I* found most similar are [Heat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/heat-metal/)/[Chill Metal](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/chill-metal/) and [Summon Swarm](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-swarm/), both 2nd level spells (3rd minimum CL).

Therefore, according to general guidance, your price would be:

2x3x2000x4(measured in rounds)x2 =

**96,000g**. Or 48,000 to craft.

---

Arguably, this could be accomplished by associating it with Magic Missile instead. The resultant cost for a 1st level spell would be:

2000x4x2=

16,000 or 8,000 to craft

Comment: Would you, under the most favorable circumstances, buy this item at this price?

Comment: No, I just wanted to provide an alternate point of view based on the literature provided. The rules allow that the outcome might not make sense and is up to the GM. But I figured having a highball answer might help with perspective (and is technically correct if not logically).

Comment: Honestly when I dredged up the table, I had no idea it would be *that* high. I'd personally estimated 20kg thinking it would probably be a 1st level spell (of which the closest is probably Magic Missile which isn't *as good* of an approximation as Heat/Chill Metal) and forgetting just how fast it multiplies up. The largest cost, as you can see, is the 4x for taking a spell effect (d4 damage) and having the option of *always* doing it, when you want. Reducing it to rounds per day or some such helps it out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost exactly a continuous version of [spiritual weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/spiritual-weapon/).

It is slightly less good in that the damage is lower, but close enough to cost it out according to [normal item rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic-items/#TOC-Magic-Item-Gold-Piece-Values): spell level x caster level x 2000. Spell level is 2, minimum caster level for that is 3, so total base cost is 12,000. No space limitation doubles the entire cost to **24,000 gold**.

That seems about right. While the damage is trivial, any stackable, slotless, free attacks break the action economy right in half. We know this from 3.5, where it came up as Persistent Spell shenanigans instead (e.g. persistent *Cloud of Knives*).

Overall though,  @KRyan's earlier comment is accurate:

> I think the entire concept is incredibly toxic and bad for the game, and so would simply recommend not having any such ioun stone at all....ultimately, 5,000 gp is not enough to prevent game-breaking abuse of this ioun stone—and I do not mean game-breaking in the “overpowered” sense, but literally in the sense of breaking the assumptions of the game’s narrative.

...which applies near-equally at 24,000gp.

Comment: *Spiritual weapon* is a lot different.  It's got a range of 100ft+10ft/lv for one, the lack of which is rather a key constraint on this stone.  It gets multiple attacks per round, hits incorporeal monsters, bypasses damage reduction, deals force damage, requires you to detect an enemy to affect it, etc.  It also requires a move action per target, which the lack of is kinda the big problem with this ioun stone.  The only similarity is that it deals damage over time, which is hardly a similarity at all-- a mundane club is more similar!

Comment: I don't see how you could break the game with this item if priced at 5,000 gp. Can you cite a precise case for one of these game abuses? (eg how many stones for which level)

Comment: @AnneAunyme This will depend on the campaign, obviously, but I think—based on [this monster chart](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/monsterCreation.html) and [this wealth chart](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement)—, that the breakpoint seems to be a 4-member party at level 11 when investing all of the party's wealth in these *ioun stones* means, without the PCs having to do anything but surround the monster, on average rolls, CR-appropriate monsters die to their 64-*stone* assault alone. Of course, no party *would* do that, but a party totally *could.* `;-)`

Comment: @HeyICanChan: my quick calculations with a party of 4 at level 11. I assume they face a CR 11 monster, which should be an easy fight: 145hp, 25AC, I assume no DR or other defensive abilities. The bonus to attack of the stone will in a good configuration be something like 11+3=14. It means half the stones hit, for a total of 32d4 or 80hp on average. so not enough to kill the monster. It may be too much, I am not sure about how much the stuff is supposed to do in an encounter.

Comment: If the monster is CR 13 instead (a medium encounter), 7/20 of the stones hit, so the average damage is 7/20*64*2.5=56 against 180hp, for CR14 it is 48 against 200hp and for CR15 40 against 220 hp. As a comparison a typical damaging spell can easily do 1d6 per level, for a total of 44d6 (if all the character are casting) or 154 damages. It will probably be "save or half", so 77 damages in the worst case.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Yeah, I know there are *a lot* of variables here. I used only hp *versus* potential damage dealt because that was simple; I'll likely be called *everything else* before somebody calls me a *statistician.* `;-)` It might be better as part of the question, but I have to ask: Why do you want to introduce this *stone* into your campaign?

Comment: @HeyICanChan: I like the style of ioun stones but I always though it could be cool if they could gravitate quickly enough that they become actual weapons. I plan to give a couple of those to a villain NPC who is obsessed about the gravitation of planets around stars (he presents himself as a priest of Sun, the only true god, but is actually just a mad scientist with a very bad plan to "save the world", and there is no sun god).

Comment: That's a darn good reason for wanting an item like this in the campaign then! (Maybe that *should* be part of this question… or included in a separate question about how to weaponize *ioun stones*?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70109/discussion-between-anne-aunyme-and-hey-i-can-chan).